# How to normalize numpy array columns differently?

Tags: python, data-science, minmax

I have a NumPy array and I want to normalize each column differently. Means 1st column should be normalized between **0 to 1**, second and third between **-1 to 1** and 4th column between **0 to 1**. How can I do it? **MinMaxScaler** scale every column between 0 to 1.

Comment: In sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler, you can choose the normalization range with the parameter feature_range:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

Comment: The problem would be it would take this max and min value for the whole matrix, while i want it to be different for different columns

Comment: I think this post might answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834242/sklearn-minmaxscaler-scale-specific-columns-only